# Creating users in laravel and removing registration

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8

I'm working on a project where I have 3 types of admins and normal users. My application shouldn't allow users to register. Only admins with certain privileges will be allowed to create users. I usually use a boolean 'is_admin' field to apply the admin role, but this will not work here because there is more than 1 role.

Do you have any idea how I can do this? Also, do I still need to use "php artisan make:auth" command?

Comment: You should be using RBAC approach to handle this kind of usecases. May be, Spatie's package will be helpful. https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/. make:auth is used to scaffold the authentication routes and views. nothing to do with user creation.

Comment: You have to maintain the roles and permissions. Spatie package is the best options you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use authentication scaffolding and disable registration like so:

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

As far as the roles/types of users go, you can use [Spatie's package](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/) like Santhosh J said. An alternative is to create a 'roles' table and a pivot table 'roles_users' to apply roles to users.